# How can I open an embedded model in matlab?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to open this model of embedded  `c280xx_adcpwmasynctest` in Matlab2015. I copy this link and I have the next error: `Undefined function or variable 'c280xx_adcpwmasynctest'`.But this is the model that I founded on the official site of Matlab. Why Matlab doesn't found this example ?

Comment: Do you have Simulink installed and licensed? Is the folder where the model file is located on your MATLAB path or your current folder?

Comment: @am304 this model isn't created by me, it's an model that Matlab needs to find automatic like this one :power_PWMGenerator3Level. When I write power_PWMGenerator3Level in command prompt in Matlab the model is opening. So I don't think I that I need to be in a specific folder.

Comment: Yes, but did you download it from the Internet?

Comment: just I write in command prompt

Comment: For this : power_PWMGenerator3Level the model is opening but for this isn't: c280xx_adcpwmasynctest

Comment: I am not so sure this particular model is included with MATLAB or not. It seems to be part of Embedded Coder. Do you have Embedded Coder installed and licensed?

Comment: @am304 I have Code Composer Studio, is not sufficient?

Comment: No. Embedded Coder is an add-on to Simulink Coder, which is an add-on to Simulink, which is an add-on to MATLAB. You should know which Mathworks products you have bought and installed.